# New Instance Spring Scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, instance, autowired

I'm using Spring boot and I would like to know if there is a way to create a new instance each time I call a specific method.

I mean, I have a singleton object dedicated to creates new instances of an autowired class and I want that each time I call the function `init` and only when I call it a new instance of that object is created.

```
@Component
public class PlatformFactoryManager {

    @Autowired
    private JiraFactory jiraFactory;

    /**
     * Obtain new factory instance of specified platform.
     */
    public IPlatformFactory getNewInstance(UserAccount userAccount, AuthenticationService authService, PlatformBean platform) {
        switch (platform.getPlatformName()) {
            case "Jira Restaurantes":
                jiraFactory.init(authService.getBy(userAccount.getUserId(), Platforms.JIRA_RESTAURANTES), platform);
                return jiraFactory;
            case "Jira Yapiko":
                jiraFactory.init(authService.getBy(userAccount.getUserId(), Platforms.JIRA_YAPIKO), platform);
                return jiraFactory;
            case "Jira FDJGS":
                jiraFactory.init(authService.getBy(userAccount.getUserId(), Platforms.JIRA_FDJGS), platform);
                return jiraFactory;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

```
@Component
public class JiraFactory implements IPlatformFactory {

    @Autowired
    private JiraBroker jiraBroker;

    private String platformName;
    private String url;

    public void init(UserAuthentication credentials, PlatformBean platform) {
        this.platform = platform;
        this.credentials = credentials;
        jiraBroker.init(platform.getUrl());
    }

...

}
```

I want a new instance of `JiraFactory` each time I call `init` and to be the same object when I use other methods.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Looks like you simply want to call `new JiraFactory()` inside of your `init` method.

Comment: If you want new instance use `new JiraBroker` every time instead of `@Autowired private JiraBroker jiraBroker;`. Because `@Autowired` creates only 1 instance at the beginning

Comment: If I call ```new``` will it destroy my autowired variables inside ```JiraBroker```?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Answer (score 1):

You can add `@Scope(scopeName = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` annotation to component also

Comment: It will create a new instance each time I use the object and I don't want that, I want a new instance just when I call this specific method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the `@Prototype` scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype).
You can refactor your `JiraFactory` component to look something like this:

```java
public class JiraFactory implements IPlatformFactory {

    private final JiraBroker jiraBroker;

    private String platformName;
    private String url;

    public JiraFactory(final JiraBroker jiraBroker, UserAuthentication credentials, PlatformBean platform) {
        this.jiraBroker=jiraBroker;
        this.platform = platform;
        this.credentials = credentials;
        jiraBroker.init(platform.getUrl());
    }
}
```

And in a `@Configuration` class, you could create the `JiraFactory` bean as a prototype bean

```
@Configuration
class JiraConfig {
   @Bean
   @Scope("prototype")
   public IPlatformFactory iPlatformFactory(final JiraBroker jiraBroker, final JiraBroker jiraBroker, UserAccount userAccount, AuthenticationService authService, PlatformBean platform) {
        switch (platform.getPlatformName()) {
            case "Jira Restaurantes":
                return new JiraFactory (jiraBroker, authService.getBy(userAccount.getUserId(), Platforms.JIRA_RESTAURANTES), platform);
            case "Jira Yapiko":
                return new JiraFactory (jiraBroker, authService.getBy(userAccount.getUserId(), Platforms.JIRA_YAPIKO), platform);
            case "Jira FDJGS":
                return new JiraFactory (jiraBroker, authService.getBy(userAccount.getUserId(), Platforms.JIRA_FDJGS), platform);
            default:
                return null; // maybe better throw exception?
        }
    }
}
```

Prototype beans behave like "normal" (singleton) beans, you will be able to `@Autowire` other services in them. However, keep in mind that Spring does not manage the life-cycle of those beans, which means it's a possible memory leak.

> In some respects, you can think of the Spring containers role when talking about a prototype-scoped bean as somewhat of a replacement for the Java 'new' operator. All life-cycle aspects past that point have to be handled by the client.

Meaning, you will have to keep track of those beans somehow, and make sure that at some point, no reference to them will exist in order for them to be garbage collected.

---

**Side note**, it is usually recommended to avoid `init()` methods. In most cases, one can replace them with constructors. If there's no way around using them, you could try using the `@PostConstruct` instead of manually calling them.

```java
@Component
class MyComponent {
   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){ // will be called by Spring once the bean/component is created
      System.out.println("Component created!"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I want both ```JiraFactory``` and  ```JiraBroker``` to be in the Spring Scope to autowire other variables, so your solution doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: You will be able to Autowire other variables in `prototype` scoped beans.